# Is there a way to select the lowest order descendants in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, children, descendant

I want to give select only the descendants of the div I'm targeting that don't have any children. Is there any way with CSS that that is possible?

Comment: If the lowest descendant is empty, you can use the `:empty` selector, but without any of your code it'll be hard to see what kind of structure you're working with.

Comment: The proper answer to your question is *No, it's not possible,  But you can set a property for parent and override it in children, effectively making the one for parent only apply when it has no children.* Another possible option, of course, is to use JavaScript.